# Problem using JQuery in Child Vue Component in a Laravel Vue Project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Laravel 9 + Vue 2.6 project that uses vue components.
I load data in the parent component through $.ajax, and to use jQuery in the parent component, I use the following to import jQuery

```
<script>
    import $ from 'jquery';

   export default {
     ....
```

I make an ajax call in the create() hook to load data for the parent component, and it works fine.

On clicking a button in the parent component, I display a child component, which is a bootstrap modal window. In the child component too, I load some data in the created() hook through $.ajax(). However, it displays an error message:

```
TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
at VueComponent.created (app.js:11936:7)
```

Of course, I don't get the desired data for the child component. However, surprisingly, the following code in the mounted() hook of the child component, which uses jQuery, works fine, and it displays the modal window:

```
mounted(){
        this.openModal();
    },
  methods: {

        openModal () {
            $('#noteCreateModal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            })

            $('#noteCreateModal').modal('show')
        },
```

And, even if I import jQuery in the child component, I still get the same error (TypeError: $.ajax is not a function).

I also want to add that I am including jquery in views/layouts/app.blade.php for bootstrap. I don't know if there is a conflict somewhere.

```
<!-- Bootstrap.js and popper.js Required for certain bootstrap components -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Any suggestion, how to fix this issue?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I used the 'slim' version of jQuery instead of the regular one. To fix the issue, I changed the jQuery version:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Besides, there was no need to use **`import $ from 'jquery';`** in Vue components (parent as well child).